# Angular2 rc1 removes all non-matrix parameters

Tags: typescript, angular

On beta I could analyze with split Location.path(), but can't now.
How do I stop the removal?

With the matrix parameters (;id=123;token=asd) everything works fine.

Tested on pure [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed).

http://localhost:5555/;id=123 - all good

http://localhost:5555/?id=123 - redirect to http://localhost:5555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query parameters support has yet to be implemented. This should be added with one of the next updates.

**update**

`preserveQueryParams` was added.

See also

- [Angular2 router keep query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898656/angular2-router-keep-query-string/39898913#39898913)
- [In angular 2 how to preserve query params and add additional query params to route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726938/in-angular-2-how-to-preserve-query-params-and-add-additional-query-params-to-rou/41782362#41782362)

Comment: And redirection can not be stopped?

Comment: I guess not. . . .