# RedirectTo with Parameter

Tags: angular

On a basic requirement, I'm trying to implement a Route that will redirect to another route and add a parameter to the Component. This is for an upload management.

Actually we have two routes:

- /documents: Show the list of documents
- /documents/upload: Show the list of documents and make a modal box with the upload form appear

The matter is that I also have GET parameter in the URL that I need to keep. But now, I would like to only the route /documents showed in the URL and not /documents/upload which can be confusing since if we close the modal, it's the same page.

So, my expected result is that going to the page /documents/upload?foo=var&toto=1234 would redirect to /documents?foo=var&toto1234 and keep a variable to tell me that I need to open the modal.

---

I've created my guard to redirect, but it seems that my queryParams aren't preserved, even with the preserveQueryParams at true. Is it an issue or am I missing something?

```
canActivate(): boolean {
    this.documentsService._isUploading = true;
    this.router.navigate(['documents'], { preserveQueryParams: true });

    return true;
}
```

And my route definition:

```
{ path: 'documents', component: DocumentsComponent}, 
{ path: 'documents/upload', component: DocumentsComponent, canActivate: [UploadRedirectionGuard]}
```

---

Final solution for those who were encountering the same issue:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    this.documentsService._isUploading = true;
    this.router.navigate(['documents'], { queryParams: state.root.queryParams });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12664

See also [Angular2 router keep query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898656/angular2-router-keep-query-string/39898913#39898913)

Currently I guess you need to use a workaround like a guard that reads the query and calls `this.router.navigate(...)` and re-adds the query when redirecting instead of the declarative `redirectTo` in the route.

You might need a `component: MyDummyComponent` instead of `redirectTo: '...'` 
There is also some change work in progress or already released (don't know) to be more forgiving in such cases.

Comment: So I would have the upload as a parameter in the URL? No possibility to pass a "hidden" parameter? I could also define it in the DocumentService, not sure if it's a good practice.

Comment: There can't be a a "hidden". What if someone bookmarks the page and opens it from the bookmark, then the parameters would be lost. Sure you can pass the query params to a service and then allow other services and components to inject it to get the query values.

Comment: Actually the link will be unique and generated, it's for a very large company intranet. I'll stick with the service parameter then. Thanks for your helpful answer!

Comment: Hey, I'm encountering a new issue while trying to implement the solution, could you take a look at my edit?

Comment: There probably aren't any query parameters anymore. You need to get the query params from the route that is first loaded and then pass them along.

Comment: Ended up by retrieving the params with RouterStateSnapshop.root.queryParams and injected it in the queryParams of NavigationExtras. Many thanks to you!