# Preventing Angular2 router from replacing original URL

Tags: angular2-routing

I have the following URL: `localhost.com:1234/?param1=abc&param2=def`

```
Route.config = [
    { path: 'first', component: 'firstComponent' },
    { path: 'second', component: 'secondComponent' }
]
```

While app initializes the URL gets replaced to `localhost.com:1234/#/first`.

How I can prevent this, so that my redirect url will be `localhost.com:1234/?param1=abc&param2=def#/first`?

Comment: Similar SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898656/angular2-router-keep-query-string

Comment: Issue got fix by adding window.history.pushState=null in my index.html page

Answer (score 0):

You can use a redirect when none of the previous router matched.

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'yourCustomComponent'}
```