# Angular 5 Query Parameters Disappear

Tags: angular, parameters, routes, angular5

When I navigate to a page with query parameters in my Angular application, the parameters end up disappearing.

For example, if I go here:

```
http://example.com:8080/TestComponent?OtherName=foo
```

If reroutes me to here:

```
http://example.com:8080/TestComponent
```

Thus, since the query parameters get erased, my subscription to `ActivatedRoute` returns nothing. This is my routing:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TestComponent, PageNotFoundComponent } from './exports/components';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'TestComponent',
        component: TestComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
    }
];
```

Subscription (`route` is an instance of `ActivatedRoute`):

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    if (params && Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
        const OTHER_NAME = params['OtherName'];
    }
});
```

Even if I remove the wildcard path, it still removes the parameters from the URL; therefore, it never goes inside the the above `if` statement. How can I prevent the query parameter from disappearing?

Comment: How do you perform the navigation?

Comment: I just type in `http://example.com:8080/TestComponent?OtherName=foo` into the address bar. Then the `Routes` array takes over and sends me to the `TestComponent` html.

Comment: The problem is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39898656/1009922). There are solutions when navigating with `routerlink` or with `Router.navigate` but not for the initial URL or when typing the URL in the address bar (as far as I know). There is a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12664) to allow a global setting to keep the query parameters.

Comment: Aww, thanks for the information. :(

Comment: How is this not a bigger issue?? This seems like an issue that would be fairly common...I'm experiencing something very similar. For me, I have a query before a hash, like so: example.com/?data=123#/home. When I go to this route, the query gets removed. Very frustrating that I can't find a solution for this. I need the query to track a Google Analytics campaign.

Answer (score 1):

This is can be an exact solution for this, but I found an approximate solution.

```
url = localhost:4200/#/test?id=1234
```

use auth-guard-service and CanActivate your page.

1.Angular routing

```
{ path: 'test', component: TestComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]}
```

2.AuthGuardService

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

constructor(private app: ApplicationService) {
    // window.location.href => gives you exact url (localhost:4200/#/test?id=1234).
    // you can parse url like this.

    id = getUrlParameterByName('id', window.location.href);
}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
   const curPage = route.url[0].path;
   if('test' === curPage) { return true; }
   else {
      // your decision...
   }
}
getUrlParameterByName(name: string, url?: any) {
    if (!url) { url = window.location.href; }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    const regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)');
    const results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) { return null; }
    if (!results[2]) { return ''; }
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Comment: You have example with url = localhost:4200/#/test?id=1234. What if the url is localhost:4200/?id=1234#/test/. How would you proceed

Comment: i showed here to how to capture url before disappearing, after that you can customize url parsing algorithm for your case.