# disappears queryParams router Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using `queryParams` to include search parameters in my url. Then I have the following:

app.routing.module.ts

```
{path: 'buscar', component: BuscarComponent}
```

component.ts

```
 goSearch() {
    this.router.navigate(['/buscar'], { queryParams: { query: 'larapa' }} );
 }
```

component.html

```
<button (click)="goSearch()">myLink</button>
```

Then the result I get `http://localhost:4200/buscar?query=larapa` but instantly `?query=larapa` disappears and as a final result I get `http://localhost:4200/buscar`

Is this normal behavior? Do I have something wrong set up? How can I do this to solve this?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898656/angular2-router-keep-query-string

Answer (score 0):

If you want remain your params, how about use app-routing paramerters?

In App.routing.module.ts

```
{path: 'buscar:query', component: BuscarComponent}
```

then you can access url like this http://localhost:yourport/buscar/larapa

Comment: I need my final path to be with this format http: // localhost: 4200/search? query=larapa since I am using algolia as a search provider