# Angular keep specific query params for all routes

Tags: angular

I've got an Angular 10 app which has to be called with an initial query parameter:

```
http://localhost:4200/?initialqueryparam=somevalue
```

I'm using hash location strategy, so further routes are like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/subroute/...?optionalqueryparamforspecificroute=anothervalue
```

What I need is to keep the initial query params for all further routes in the application. The url therefore should look like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/?initialqueryparam=somevalue/#/subroute/...?optionalqueryparamforspecificroute=anothervalue
```

Is this possible and if yes: how?

**Update 1:**

In the meantime I've implemented [this hack using ngrx store](http://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12664#issuecomment-673349277). The disadvantage is, that the query params are not added after the base url but after the subroute:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/subroute/...?optionalqueryparamforspecificroute=anothervalue&initialqueryparam=somevalue
```

This has two disadvantages:

1. My menu items which are styled with the help of the `routerLinkActive` directive are not styled correctly anymore because the configured route is not recoginzed due to the appended query param
2. When Right-Clicking on a menu item (browser context menu opens) and selecting "open in new tab" the query params get missed as the ngrx effect is not called in this case
3. When calling the app with this url, I cannot use `window.location.search` like I do with the initial url to get the initial query param but I have to dig out the queryparam from `window.location.hash` with ugly string splitting.

It would be much better if there was a way to add the initial param directly behind the base url. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 router keep query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898656/angular2-router-keep-query-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This github answer](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12664#issuecomment-726015672) did the trick for me:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF, HashLocationStrategy, PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HashPreserveQueryLocationStrategy extends HashLocationStrategy {
    private readonly initialQueryParam: string;

    constructor(
        _platformLocation: PlatformLocation,
        @Optional() @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) _baseHref?: string
    ) {
        super(_platformLocation, _baseHref);
        this.initialQueryParam = window.location.search || '';
    }

    prepareExternalUrl(internal: string): string {
        const hash = super.prepareExternalUrl(internal);
        return this.initialQueryParam + hash;
    }
}
```

And in app module:

```
providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashPreserveQueryLocationStrategy }]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you'd want to just configure some global property directly within your router config that would persist the query params, but I do not believe that is possible (a very rare use case).

What is available however is the ability to persist query params directly within the `Router` though.

So what you could do is enforce some specific routing rules so that `queryParamsHandling` is set to `preserve` when you route to whatever link you're going to.

```
this.router.navigate(['/view2'], { queryParams: { page: 2 },  queryParamsHandling: "preserve"
});
```

Additionally, you could potentially automate this entire process if you are using a Navigation [Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) or [NgRx Router Store](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store).

So no support for a single switch to flip, but as always, there's a cocktail you can make to fill that void.

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#queryParamsHandling

You might also want to check out this PR https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12664

Comment: I ended up implementing this hack using ngrx store: github.com/angular/angular/issues/12664#issuecomment-673349277. This works well within the application. Still not working: Open a link in a new tab won't add the query param to the url. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you opening the url in a new tab?

Comment: right-clicking on a menu item (browser context menu opens) -> open in new tab

Comment: Can you update your code? Have you tried doing a console.log or something on page load to see if it's a problem with the query params being set vs angular removing them with the location strategy?

Comment: Any further ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I created a package containing an `AdvancedRouter` and `AdvancedRouterLinkDirective` that allows you to specify which queryparams should be preserved and which should be dropped: [Github repo](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-router)

[Here's the place where it's configured](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.module.ts#L78)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Angular routing module you could add a child below your initial parameter.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: ':initialqueryparam',
  component: YourComponent,
  children: [
    {
       path: 'subroute/:optionalqueryparamforspecificroute',
       component YourComponent,
       children: [

       ]
    }
  ]
```

and in the component:

```
 this._router.navigate([`${initialParam}/subroute/${optionalqueryparamforspecificroute}`]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable()
export class PreserveQueryPathLocationStrategy extends PathLocationStrategy {
  private readonly query: string;
  private readonly preservedKeys: string[] = ['affiliate_id']; // this can be extended to be passed from constructor using DI etc.
  constructor(
    _platformLocation: PlatformLocation,
    @Optional() @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) _baseHref?: string
  ) {
    super(_platformLocation, _baseHref);
    // TODO: fix if use SSR
    this.query = location && location.search ? location.search.substr(1) : '';
  }

  prepareExternalUrl(internal: string): string {
    const path = super.prepareExternalUrl(internal);
    if (!this.query || !Object.keys(this.preservedKeys).length) {
      return path;
    }

    const pathQueryIndex = path.indexOf('?');
    const pathQueryEndWithAndChar = pathQueryIndex === -1 && path.endsWith('&');
    const pathQueryKeyvalues: string[] =
      pathQueryIndex === -1
        ? []
        : this.extractKeyvaluesFromQuery(path.substr(pathQueryIndex + 1));

    const keyvalues = this.extractKeyvaluesFromQuery(this.query);
    const preservedKeyvalues: string[] = [];
    keyvalues.forEach(kv => {
      this.preservedKeys.forEach(pk => {
        if (
          !pathQueryKeyvalues.includes(kv) &&
          (kv === pk || kv.startsWith(`${pk}=`))
        ) {
          preservedKeyvalues.push(kv);
        }
      });
    });
    if (preservedKeyvalues.length) {
      return pathQueryIndex === -1
        ? `${path}?${preservedKeyvalues.join('&')}`
        : `${path}${
            pathQueryEndWithAndChar ? '' : '&'
          }${preservedKeyvalues.join('&')}`;
    } else {
      return path;
    }
  }

  extractKeyvaluesFromQuery(query: string): string[] {
    let keyvalues: string[] = [];
    let queryStr = query;
    while (queryStr.startsWith('&')) {
      queryStr = queryStr.substr(1);
    }
    while (queryStr.endsWith('&')) {
      queryStr = queryStr.substr(0, queryStr.length - 1);
    }
    if (queryStr) {
      keyvalues = queryStr.split('&');
    }
    return keyvalues;
  }
}
```