# Retaining value of query params in angular component

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

I am working on a angular application. I have a component say component1 in which I am getting a value as query params as follows:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';

 constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute)
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.user = params.user;
    });
}
```

In this component only I have a button. When user click on that button it is routed to component2. On component2 I have a back button, which I when clicked I get routed again to component1. When I return to component1 from component2, I can see this.user value get set to undefined. Is there is any way when I return to component1 from component2, the value which was there already must be retained?

I already tried all the solutions mentioned on [Angular2 router keep query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898656/angular2-router-keep-query-string), but none works for me.

Answer (score 0):

[queryParamsHandling](https://angular.io/api/router/QueryParamsHandling)

```
router.navigate(['/component2'], { queryParamsHandling: "preserve" });
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation i recommend share variable state inside the whole application using such library like rxjs :

Going step by step .. first create new service SharedService contain two variables :
(i recommend to take a look on this link to learn more about behaviorSubject and Observable if you don't have idea about the it [BehaviorSubject vs Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable))

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

user = new BehaviorSubject({name: 'default name'}) ;  
userObservable = this.user.asObservable() ; 

constructor() { }


changeUser(newObject){
   this.user.next(newObject) ; 
 }
}
```

moving to the component1 . First we have to subscribe to the SharedService userObservable variable . and have the ability to change the service variable value or moving to component 2 :

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { SharedService }   from '../services/shared.service'
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
  })

  export class Component1 implements OnInit {

  user ; 
 constructor(private sharedSerivce : SharedService,
        private router : Router 
 ) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.sharedSerivce.user.subscribe(currentUser=>{
  this.user= currentUser ; 
 })
 }

saveUser() {
    this.sharedSerivce.changeUser({name : 'new user '}) ; 
}

goToComponent2(){
  this.router.navigate(['/component2'])
 }
}
```

and the component1 html file will be as follow :

```
<h1>Component 1</h1>
<p>current user name is {{user.name}}</p>

<button (click)="saveUser()">
 change user name to 'new user'
</button>
<br>



<button (click)="goToComponent2()">  
goToComponent2
</button>
```

in the component 2 also we have to subscribe to the service userObservable variable and even changing this value or returning to component1

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedService } from '../services/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.scss']
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {
  user ; 
  constructor(private sharedSerivce : SharedService,
        private router : Router 
 ) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {

    //each time the component 1 loaded will synchronise the value of its user proprty with the value saved in the serivce
    this.sharedSerivce.user.subscribe(currentUser=>{
      this.user= currentUser ; 
    })
  }

  saveUser() {
    this.sharedSerivce.changeUser({name: 'default user'}) ;
  }

  goToComponent1(){
    this.router.navigate(['/component1'])
  }
}
```

also the component2 html content will not be far away than component 1

```
<h1>Component 2</h1>
<p>current user name is {{user.name}}</p>
<button (click)="saveUser()">
change user name to 'default user'
</button>
<br>


<button (click)="goToComponent1()">
Back To Component1
</button>
```