# Why is the login path loaded twice in my code below?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean-stack

Below are codes of my app.component.ts and another module called login. I have setup router for navigation to login component. I will first put down my code and then state my problem after that.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        // if(accessToken) {
        //  this.router.navigateByUrl('/posts');
        // } else {
        //  this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        // }
    }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    paramsSubscription: Subscription | undefined;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.paramsSubscription = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            const accessToken = params['access_token'] || localStorage.getItem('access_token');
            console.log('ACCESS TOKEN: ', accessToken);
            if(accessToken) {
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken);
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.paramsSubscription?.unsubscribe();
    }

    loginViaFacebook() {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook';
    }

    loginViaGoogle() {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google';
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass a query parameter to the `/login` path and if the same is found I want to redirect the user to `/posts`.
The path I am trying to access is `http://localhost:4200/login?access_token=abcdef`.
There is an unexpected behaviour that I am observing. When I comment the navigation code in `ngOnInit()` of `app.component.ts` I am able to capture the queryParam in my `login.component.ts`. However if I keep it uncommented, I can see the queryParam getting logged once and the login path is again called and this time there is no query param(It is empty).

I am new to angular. Is there something related to routers that I am missing?

UPDATE: It is not about navigating from app.component.ts to login route. Even if I directly go in browser and hit /login route with queryParam it is loading the path twice. Once with the queryParam and another time consecutively without any params.

Comment: If I understood it correctly you just need to retain the query params while navigating to new path. May be check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898656/angular2-router-keep-query-string