# In angular 2 how to preserve query params and add additional query params to route

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, query-string

For example I am on route `/cars?type=coupe` and I want to navigate to the same endpoint with additional query params (but keeping existing one). I am trying something like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['/cars']" [queryParams]="{model: 'renault'}" preserveQueryParams>Click</a>
```

The initial query params are preserved (type=cars) but added ones (model=renault) are ignored. Is this expected/correct behavior or is some kind of bug? Looks like preserveQueryParams has priority over queryParams? Is there any other smooth solution?

Comment: When using Anguar 4, I see preserveQueryParams is deprecated, use queryParamsHandling instead ???

Answer (score 49):

In Angular 4+, `preserveQueryParams` has been deprecated in favor of `queryParamsHandling`. The options are either `'merge'` or `'preserve'`.

In-code example (used in `NavigationExtras`):

```
this.router.navigate(['somewhere'], { queryParamsHandling: "preserve" });
```

In-template example:

```
<a [routerLink]="['somewhere']" queryParamsHandling="merge">
```

Comment: Great answer! might want to use merge in your first example as it is the setting the OP wants

Comment: Thank you for your answer, This should be the accepted answer, I have no idea why people are answering with a complex answers on a totally wrong directions!, as a RoR developer, never seen such as this mess anywhere among the community, and I'm saying this because I've had a real hard times finding a simple answer for a simple question :S, Thanks again for your answer :)

Answer (score 14):

It just works this way unfortunately:

`const q = preserveQueryParams ? this.currentUrlTree.queryParams : queryParams;`

You could try to add custom directive like this:

```
@Directive({selector: 'a[routerLink][merge]'})
export class RouterLinkDirective implements OnInit
{

    @Input()
    queryParams: {[k: string]: any};

    @Input()
    preserveQueryParams: boolean;


    constructor(private link:RouterLinkWithHref, private route: ActivatedRoute )
    {
    }

    public ngOnInit():void
    {
        this.link.queryParams = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, this.route.snapshot.queryParams), this.link.queryParams);
        console.debug(this.link.queryParams);
    }
}


<a [routerLink]="['/cars']" merge [queryParams]="{model: 'renault'}">Click</a>
```

---

Update: See DarkNeuron answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue and also already a pull request to make `preserveQueryParams` a router setting instead of a per navigation setting

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12664
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/12979
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13806

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled using `relativeTo` and `queryParamsHandling` properties.

Try like this:

```
constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _router: Router)


this._router.navigate(
    [],
    {
      relativeTo: this._route,
      queryParams: { model: 'renault' },
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
 });
```