# Build query string params through a series of router links

Tags: angular, routerlink

Is it possible to configure router links to simply add to the query string so that we can build a query string through a series of links?

Given the url:

```
http://localhost/app
```

And a link somewhere on the page similar to this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['.']" [queryParams]="{ foo: 1 }">link 1</a>
```

Would link to:

```
http://localhost/app?foo=1
```

Given a second link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['.']" [queryParams]="{ bar: 1 }">link 2</a>
```

Is it possible to produce the route:

```
http://localhost/app?foo=1&bar=1
```

rather than overwriting the current query string? I suspect it's possible by listening to the router events and working it out manually but I wonder if it isn't possible through some configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple enough to get the current query params from the activated route and shallow copying them with modifications as necessary for returning to the router.

In the html:

```
<a [routerLink]="['.']" [queryParams]="getQueryParams(1)">link 1</a>
```

in the component:

```
getQueryParams(id: number) {
  //this.queryParams retrieved by subscribing to the activated route on init
  let queryParams = Object.assign({}, this.queryParams);
  queryParams['foo'] = id;
  return queryParams;
}
```

Which will return the key value pair object that the router expects for the query params with the parameter in question either added or overridden with any existing ones intact.

Answer (score 0):

There is preserveQueryParams that might keep the foo=1 while you navigate to bar=1 i haven't tried it but the docs say it can be used like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['.']" [queryParams]="{ bar: 1 }" preserveQueryParams>link 2</a>
```

Comment: Yeah that doesn't appear to work in conjunction with supplying any query params.

Comment: hmm yea it looks like it gets overridden still. There looks like a good answer here that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726938/in-angular-2-how-to-preserve-query-params-and-add-additional-query-params-to-rou/41779740

Comment: Cheers for that. That's essentially the same question and has answered mine conclusively (there is no native config solution). If I come up with a simple solution I may post it otherwise  this question is redundant.